# Detect if webgl hardware acceleration is enabled

Tags: javascript, browser, webgl, hardware-acceleration

Are there a way to detect if browser uses hardware or software rendering for webgl?

I would like to not to show the webgl parts if software rendering is enabled(it is very slow, and better of with a placeholder)

Currently I'am thinking about doing some tests while page is loading and set a flag based on the performance of those tests. It sounds kind of wonky to me though, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect software vs hardware webGL render mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704224/detect-software-vs-hardware-webgl-render-mode)

Comment: Just to test, I switched off "hardware acceleration" in Chrome: it shows me a canvas black background - FF draws somewhat altered colors but in IE has no visible effect,  also performance (fps) is still the same. Maybe You can try the canvas colors comparison test, like in "WebGL Report". But I believe every browser will behave differently here.

Comment: Just to see - have you found a solution @Davinel

Answer (score -2):

If you are using ThreeJS ( and i assume you do) , you can always check:

```
Detector.webgl
```

If false it means the browser blocks WebGl technology for some reason. In other words `Detector.webgl` will evaluate to true if hardware renderer is available.

Comment: I do know how to detect webgl support in general. Question was - how to detect software/hardware rendering mode.

Comment: This only detects if the browser supports WebGL. However, the browser might be using a slow CPU-based fallback for the GPU. That is what this question is about: detecting whether or not the browser is using that slow CPU-based-fallback.